# woocommerce "publish ""product"" webhook

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to add an action whenever the admin publishes a product, but the WP hook publish_post does not trigger then - even though a wc product is just another type of post.

I haven't found a woocommerce hook that triggers when a product is published.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

The action hook `publish_post` doesn't work for custom post types. You need to use the following format: `publish_{$custom_post_type}`

As you are using Woocommerce this post type is ***product*** so you want to use:
 `publish_product`.